# Check if children exist in Active record collection with ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, ancestry

I have `Category` model with `ancestry` attached.
I need to get children and boolean value if they have own children. (with collection)
I'm trying to get this done by using `joins`

Here is the structure

Category1 id: 1, ancestry: nil
  Child1 id: 2, ancestry: 1
    Child2 id: 3, ancestry: 1/2

So in order to get proper joins (check if `Child1` has children) I need to use this where clause with current `ancestry` and `id` value

`WHERE "categories"."ancestry" = '1/2'`

How I can do something like this in postgres? `'ancestry/id'` or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I would suggest to use one of these ancestry methods children, children_ids & has_children? well if postgres in not obligatory

Comment: @Onur it works with one node. I need to check with collection. Iterate each record is not an option if you have 200+ records. My previous implementation was with `parent_id` and it was simple join with with column.